# Rewrite rule for zip files not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://(www\.)website.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|bmp|zip|rar)$ - [F]
```

I've tried this and every variation of it, in my httpd.conf file, my ssl.conf file and my .htaccess, clearing my cache in between checks. No matter what I do, this directive gets ignored with no error logs. The following rewrite rule is working no problem at the tail-end of my httpd.conf file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

I have of course played around with trying http, https, http(s) etc.

What's going on here?

I have made no progress on this so far.

I was able to block access to zips entirely with

```
<FilesMatch ".zip">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from All
</FilesMatch>
```

But it is crucial that the zips can be accessed from my server. Unfortunately, placing them outside webroot and serving them up with PHP isn't an option in this exact scenario either. I understand this is the poorest sort of hotlinking protection there is, but I very much want just that little bit, and can't seem to make this simple Rewrite work at all. No erros anywhere to work with....

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME}%{HTTP_REFERER} !^(.*)https?://\1/
RewriteRule \.(js|css|png|jpg|zip) - [R=404,L]
```

Also, did, not, work.....

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer "^https://www\.website\.com/" banimages=1
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer "^https://website\.com/" banimages=1
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer "^$" banimages=1
<FilesMatch "\.(gif|png|jpe?g|zip)$">
  Order Allow,Deny
  Allow from env=banimages=1
</FilesMatch>
```

This ALSO didn't work, it just blocked access entirely. Tried http and https.

---

Still no change on this. No matter what I do, I can't get this SIMPLE rewriterule to work, no error logs, no syntax erros on restarting, nadda.

Somebody has to have a clue about this.

---

Gone through my entire httpd.conf and ssl.conf files, found nothing that stood out that should be blocking this...

---

Changing all instances of AllowOverride to All in my configs also hasn't changed anything. :(

Comment: Does it work when you remove conditions?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to deter external hotlinking to .zip files on my server. What do you mean by remove condition @DusanBajic

Comment: just remove those two `RewriteCond` lines (only as a test)

Comment: It makes no change, I can still access the zip files and no errors. Just to be clear, did oyu mean remove the entire two lines, or JUST the words RewriteCond? I remove the whole lines

Comment: Find `AllowOverride` directive in your .conf file(s) and change it to `AllowOverride All`

Comment: I went through and changed every instance of AllowOverride to All in all of my configs, no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This took WAY too long. BEFORE last < /VirtualHost> tag in ssl.conf put

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?website.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|zip)$ - [NC,F,L]
```

replcing website.com with your domain obviously. This will block both people hotlinking from an external site, AND blank referrers (people going to www.website.com/image.zip), which you may or may not want, remove RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$ if that part gives your users issues.

Enjoy, frustrated folk from the future.